# Variable value not moved

Tags: rust

Given the code below:

```rust
let x = 5;
let y = x;
println!("{}", x);
```

As far as I have been reading, I learned that the above code would end up in error as the value of `x` has been moved to `y`. But it doesn't work that way. I have tried the above code with integers and strings, it just works.

Comment: type that implement copy are not moved but copied. https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=cdca162a2aebe1c3921df6815195deff <= "I have tried the above code with integers and strings" press X to doubt

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does Rust provide move semantics?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29490670/how-does-rust-provide-move-semantics)

Comment: @Stargateur, thanks for the speedy response, I tried let x = "hello" , the code worked and as you mentioned on your comment when I tried let x = String::new("Hello") it didn't. I guess i am getting whats wrong here. When it is let x = "hello", it is a str which will be in allocated memory and it has copy trait implemented, is that right?

Comment: `"hello"` is a `&'static str` it not allocated in the "heap" but directly "somewhere" depend on your OS etc. Anyway, reference implement copy so yes this work with reference. `&str` != `String` == View != Object https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch08-02-strings.html#what-is-a-string

Comment: Perfect thanks, Stargateur

Comment: @Sumchans it's called a [string slice](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html). And yes, they 'are Copy as well as primitive integers.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can an integer variable still be used after assigning it to another variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74503570/why-can-an-integer-variable-still-be-used-after-assigning-it-to-another-variable)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primitives types by default implement Copy trait. So, in this case, value of x is copied into y. Try doing the same thing with anything that doesn't implement copy trait like String, you will encounter a compile time error. It is inefficient to create a copy every time you assign a variable to another variable. However, certain things can be trivially copied.

Comment: Okay thanks, Where to find the documentation for that, like I want to know what traits are included with what types?

Comment: See look at this documentation. This may be meaty but take some time to go through the documentation. It will clarify some of the stuff
https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/trait.Copy.html

Comment: have been looking into it. Just got confused with a few stuff. I guess I am getting it. Thanks again.