# Why can an integer variable still be used after assigning it to another variable?

Tags: rust

I am trying to understand how the ownership works in Rust. Consider the following simple example:

```
let u_own = 3432;
let d_own = u_own;
println!("{}", u_own);
```

The compiler does not complain, although the ownership from the value `3432` has moved to `d_own`. The last statement which is the `println!` prints the number `3432` without any problem on the console.

I was expecting that the compiler will complain because the ownership has been moved.

Comment: Numeric types don't have move semantics, they have copy semantics, see https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch04-01-what-is-ownership.html#stack-only-data-copy

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ownership never moves. For any type that is marked as `std::marker::Copy` (we say the type "is Copy"), the assignment operator does not move ownership. It creates a copy of that value.

Primitive types in Rust are `Copy` by default, and you are free to derive that marker on any of your own types, though you should reserve it for small ones. Simple enums are commonly made `Copy`.

If you used a type that is not `Copy`, then your expected behaviour will arise. E.g. a `String`:

```rust
fn main() {
    let u_own = String::new();
    let d_own = u_own;
    println!("{}", u_own);
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=bba14f8dcf6225285736f22c0f389acd)

```
error[E0382]: borrow of moved value: `u_own`
 --> src/main.rs:4:20
  |
2 |     let u_own = String::new();
  |         ----- move occurs because `u_own` has type `String`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
3 |     let d_own = u_own;
  |                 ----- value moved here
4 |     println!("{}", u_own);
  |                    ^^^^^ value borrowed here after move
  |
  = note: this error originates in the macro `$crate::format_args_nl` which comes from the expansion of the macro `println` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0382`.
```

Comment: For internal types I tend to impl `Copy` only for small types, but [for public types you should impl it any time you can](https://rust-lang.github.io/api-guidelines/interoperability.html). Note that implementing `Copy` can give your type some optimizations by specializations in std.